# FIREBASE and React Native ERROR when trying to create a new node with child (then is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I can't create a new node with a child.

```
export const salvarDisciplinas = ({ terca}) => {
return dispatch => {
        var estudante = firebase.database().ref('DiasSemana/');
        estudante.child("DiasSemanaDisciplinas").child("Segunda").child(terca)

        .then(value => cadastro_disciplinas_sucesso(dispatch))
        .catch(erro => cadastro_disciplinas_erro(erro, dispatch));
}}
```

I would like to create this way.

```
DiasSemana
 |
 |__DiasSemanaDisciplinas
       |
       |__Segunda
            |
            |__terca
```

The error generated is: aluno.child ("DiasSemanaDisciplinas"). Child ("Segunda"). Child (Monday) .then is not a function.

I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `set()` to add a value to the attribute:

```
export const salvarDisciplinas = ({ terca}) => {
return dispatch => {
        var estudante = firebase.database().ref('DiasSemana/');
        estudante.child("DiasSemanaDisciplinas").child("Segunda").child("terca").set(terca)

        .then(value => cadastro_disciplinas_sucesso(dispatch))
        .catch(erro => cadastro_disciplinas_erro(erro, dispatch));
}}
```

Also since `set()` returns a `Promise` then you can use the `then()` method.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#returns-promise--any-_1

Comment: it worked Peter, thank you very much for your help and thanks for the link.